# ASP.NET Core not finding npm

Tags: asp.net, node.js, npm

I have a new Asp.NET Core Web / React application.

When I try to run it I get the error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors
>   occurred. (Failed to start 'npm'. To resolve this:.
>
> [1] Ensure that 'npm' is installed and can be found in one of the PATH
>   directories.

I have a PATH variable set up:

> C:\Program Files\nodejs

In this folder is `node.exe`

Do I need to install something into the project?

I have made no other changes to the project since creating it from the VS Web Application template. I just want it to run...

The full path error list:

> Current PATH enviroment variable is: C:\Program
>   Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.9\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program
>   Files\TortoiseHg\;C:\Program Files (x86)\PKWARE\pkzipc;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program
>   Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program
>   Files\Mercurial\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program
>   Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\010
>   Editor;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Emulator
>   Manager\1.0\;C:\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client
>   SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_162\bin;C:\clojure-clr-1.8.0-Release 4.0\Release
>   4.0\clojure;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance
>   Toolkit\;C:\Users\stuarts.cargo\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Elm
>   Platform\0.18\bin;C:\Users\stuarts\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Scripts\;C:\Users\stuarts\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\;C:\Users\stuarts\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Nuget\nuget.exe;C:\utils;C:\Users\stuarts\AppData\Roaming\Python35\Scripts;C:\Program
>   Files\7-Zip;C:\Users\stuarts\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Users\stuarts\AppData\Local\Programs\Fiddler;C:\Scripts;C:\Nuget;C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft VS
>   Code\bin;C:\Users\stuarts.lein\bin;C:\Users\stuarts\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\clojure-clr-1.8.0-Release
>   4.0\Release 4.0;C:\Users\stuarts.dotnet\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.7.2
>   Tools;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs;

You can see node is the last one...

Comment: I've got the exact same problem 8 months later. did you or anyone find a solution?

Comment: @Alan I didn't, unfortunately. My .netcore / React experiment was very short lived...

Comment: Directly wrote   spa.Options.SourcePath = "C:\\Users\\abcd\\source\\repos\\AngularCoreDotNet\\ClientApp";.